# how to solve ValueError at /register in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a sign up with Django but after filling the form, I keep getting this `ValueError at /register` as an error requesting that the username be set. I am new to Django and I don't seem to understand what is expected.
Below are my codes for signup form, the views.py and the resulting error respectively

Signup form:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<h5>{{message}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" action="register" name="registerForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="username "/>
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="email" name="email "/>
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <p>Repeat Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        confirm_password = request.POST.get('confirm_password')
        
        if password==confirm_password:
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Username Taken')
                return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                messages.info(request, 'Email Taken')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
                user.save()
                
                return redirect('/')
                
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Password does not match')
            return redirect('register')
    else:
        return render(request, 'register.html')
```

Error:

```
ValueError at /register
The given username must be set
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/register
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The given username must be set
Exception Location: C:\Users\User\Envs\myapp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py, line 144, in _create_user
Raised during:  myapp.views.register
Python Executable:  C:\Users\User\Envs\myapp\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.4
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Python_journey\\djangoTut\\myproject',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Envs\\myapp',
 'C:\\Users\\User\\Envs\\myapp\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 22 Nov 2022 07:17:35 +0000
```

Comment: Just remove white-space from, for example, `<input type="text" name="username "/>` so that it becomes `<input type="text" name="username" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are doing wrong here.

Change this:

```
action="register"
```

To this:

```
action="{% url 'register' %}" #You need to write name of this register route.
```

**OR**

Simply you can try this way:

```
action="/register/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your signup.html:

```
{% for message in messages %}
<h5>{{message}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" action="/register/" name="registerForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="username "/>
    <!-- blank space in this input -->
    <p>Email:</p>
    <input type="email" name="email "/>
    <!-- blank space in this input -->
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <p>Repeat Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="confirm_password"/><br>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

You have blankspaces inside your input tag "name" value. So these values are not being passed to your view inside your request, you get a None value instead.

And when trying to retrieve an object with this value, the exception is raised.

```
User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
```

I would like to recommend to retrieve your model by using a try/except to handle errors, or use the Django [get-object-or-404 shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) before checking for its existence.